# Warn : Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0)

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I am building ecommerce app using react-native I just encountered an error which i don't know what it mean

Error is "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'err.response.data')"

I have used "err.response.data" in  2-3 file but i have mentioned code of one file

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';
import {returnErrors} from './errorActions';
import {ADD_TO_CART, CHECK_OUT} from './types';
import {
  AllDispatchProp,
  API_URI,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
  DELETE_PRODUCT,
  LOADED_PRODUCTS,
  LOADING_PRODUCTS,
  SENT_PRODUCT,
} from './types';

export const addProduct = ({
  title,
  price,
  imageUrl,
  desc,
}: {
  title: string;
  price: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  desc: string;
}) => async (dispatch: AllDispatchProp, getState: any) => {
  const auth = getState().auth;
  const data = JSON.stringify({title, price, imageUrl, desc, user: auth.user});
  const token = AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  //* Store a product
  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
    data,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({type: CLEAR_ERRORS, payload: null});
      dispatch({type: SENT_PRODUCT, payload: res.data._doc});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(
          err.response.data,
          err.response.status,
          'PRODUCT_POST_FAIL',
        ),
      );
    });
};

//* Load Amazon Products *//
export const loadProducts = () => async (dispatch: AllDispatchProp) => {
  dispatch({type: LOADING_PRODUCTS, payload: null});
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  //* Load products from url *//
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({type: LOADED_PRODUCTS, payload: res.data});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(
          err.response.data,
          err.response.status,
          'LOAD_PRODUCT_FAIL',
        ),
      );
    });
};

export const deleteProduct = (_id: string) => async (
  dispatch: AllDispatchProp,
) => {
  const data = JSON.stringify({_id});
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  axios({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
    data,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({type: DELETE_PRODUCT, payload: res.data._id});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(
          err.response.data,
          err.response.status,
          'DELETE_PRODUCT_FAIL',
        ),
      );
    });
};

//* Amazon add to cart *//
export const addToCart = (_id: string) => async (
  dispatch: AllDispatchProp,
  getState: any,
) => {
  const {products, cartProducts} = getState().product;
  const cartProduct = cartProducts.filter((p: any) => p._id === _id);
  const isInCart = cartProduct.length > 0;
  const data = JSON.stringify({_id});
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  if (!isInCart) {
    axios({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-app-token': token,
      },
      data,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: res.data});
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(
          returnErrors(
            err.response.data,
            err.response.status,
            'ADD_TO_CART_FAIL',
          ),
        );
      });
  }
};

export const productCheckOut = () => async (dispatch: AllDispatchProp) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({type: CHECK_OUT, payload: res.data});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'CHECKOUT_FAIL'),
      );
    });
};

export const clearCart = () => async (dispatch: AllDispatchProp) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');
  axios({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product/clear`,
    headers: {
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then(() => {
      return loadProducts();
    })
    .catch(() => {});
};
```

I dont from where this error occurred but I really need help in this on

This is the "returnErrors" file

```
import {GET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS} from './types';

// RETURN ERRORS
export const returnErrors = (
  msg: string,
  status: string | number,
  id: string | null,
) => {
  return {
    type: GET_ERRORS,
    payload: {msg, status, id},
  };
};

// CLEAR ERRORS
export const clearErrors = () => {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_ERRORS,
  };
};
```

After editing;

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';
import {returnErrors} from './dist/errorActions';
import {ADD_TO_CART, CHECK_OUT} from './dist/types';
import {
  AllDispatchProp,
  API_URI,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
  DELETE_PRODUCT,
  LOADED_PRODUCTS,
  LOADING_PRODUCTS,
  SENT_PRODUCT,
} from './types';

export const addProduct = ({
  title,
  price,
  imageUrl,
  desc,
}: {
  title: string;
  price: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  desc: string;
}) => async (dispatch: AllDispatchProp, getState: any) => {
  const auth = getState().auth;
  const data = JSON.stringify({title, price, imageUrl, desc, user: auth.user});
  const token = AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  //* Store a product
  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
    data,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({type: CLEAR_ERRORS, payload: null});
      dispatch({type: SENT_PRODUCT, payload: res.data._doc});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(
          err.response?.data ?? 'your default msg',
          err.response?.status ?? 'your default status',
          'PRODUCT_POST_FAIL',
        ),
      );
    });
};

//* Load app Products *//
export const loadProducts = () => async (dispatch: AllDispatchProp) => {
  dispatch({type: LOADING_PRODUCTS, payload: null});
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  //* Load products from url *//
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({type: LOADED_PRODUCTS, payload: res.data});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(
          err.response.data,
          err.response.status,
          'LOAD_PRODUCT_FAIL',
        ),
      );
    });
};

export const deleteProduct = (_id: string) => async (
  dispatch: AllDispatchProp,
) => {
  const data = JSON.stringify({_id});
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  axios({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
    data,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({type: DELETE_PRODUCT, payload: res.data._id});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(
          err.response.data,
          err.response.status,
          'DELETE_PRODUCT_FAIL',
        ),
      );
    });
};

//* app add to cart *//
export const addToCart = (_id: string) => async (
  dispatch: AllDispatchProp,
  getState: any,
) => {
  const {products, cartProducts} = getState().product;
  const cartProduct = cartProducts.filter((p: any) => p._id === _id);
  const isInCart = cartProduct.length > 0;
  const data = JSON.stringify({_id});
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  if (!isInCart) {
    axios({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'x-app-token': token,
      },
      data,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({type: ADD_TO_CART, payload: res.data});
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(
          returnErrors(
            err.response.data,
            err.response.status,
            'ADD_TO_CART_FAIL',
          ),
        );
      });
  }
};

export const productCheckOut = () => async (dispatch: AllDispatchProp) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');

  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product`,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({type: CHECK_OUT, payload: res.data});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(
        returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, 'CHECKOUT_FAIL'),
      );
    });
};

export const clearCart = () => async (dispatch: AllDispatchProp) => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token');
  axios({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: `${API_URI}/api/product/clear`,
    headers: {
      'x-app-token': token,
    },
  })
    .then(() => {
      return loadProducts();
    })
    .catch(() => {});
};
```

and returnErrors file
**Note: *when i am editing returnError code i got an error "Unexpected Token" on question mark symbol***

```
import {GET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS} from './types';

// RETURN ERRORS
export const returnErrors = (
    msg: string | undefined,
    status: string | number | undefined,
    id: string | null,
  ) => {
    return {
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: {msg??"your default msg", status??"your default status", id},
    };
  };

// CLEAR ERRORS
export const clearErrors = () => {
  return {
    type: CLEAR_ERRORS,
  };
};
```

One more thing whenever i'm trying to register in app it throw this error only(i hope u understand what i'm trying to say)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can check if the params for returnErrors() exist before passing them

```
.catch((err) => {
      
         dispatch(
           returnErrors(
           err.response?.data ?? "your default msg",
           err.response?.status ?? "your default status",
           'PRODUCT_POST_FAIL',
           ),
          );
      
    });
```

or you can teach your returnErrors function how to deal with undefined params

```
 export const returnErrors = (
    msg: string | undefined,
    status: string | number | undefined,
    id: string | null,
  ) => {
    return {
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: {msg:msg??"your default msg", status:status??"your default status", id},
    };
  };
```

Comment: No its not working its still giving me the same error

Comment: can you show how your code is looking like after the edit, and the error you're getting please

Comment: sure i have edited the session please check and help me i really need solve this

Comment: I have edited the second part of my answer and fixed the syntax error, should be working now. please mark it as solved if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to provide the signature of the `returnErrors` function for a better analysis but I think this function expects an object as its first argument while `err.response.data` could be undefined. That would throw a type error in an asynchronous part of the code, resulting in the `Unhandled Promise Rejection`.

To resolve this, you could check the kind of data you send to `returnErrors` every time you call it, or make the function `returnErrors` receive any kind of data and format it accordingly. I would rather implement the latter.

Comment: I have mentioned the "returnErrors" file above can u check and tell me if anything is wrong